# Unmounting a filesystem

Tags: unmounting

I am trying to unmount a filesystem.  The mount point of the filesystem is  `/one/two/three/four`, and the name of the device file is `/dev/sdb8`.  The command that I executed to unmount the filesystem was:

```
# unmount /one/two/three/four
```

The current directory was `/one/two/three/four` when the command was executed.  Why was I unable to unmount the filesystem?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure the command was `unmount` and not `umount`?

The command will fail if your current working directory is the mount point or a subdirectory of the mount point. You cannot unmount the filesystem if it's in use.
If the device is not otherwise "busy" it should suffice to change the working dir to another directory before unmounting.

Answer (score 1):

It should be "umount" command, not "unmount".